# sokoban error in test case

Tags: c++, game-development

Construct a graph in which the vertices are tuples (Sx,Sy,Bx,By) describing the current position of the Sokoban player, (Sx,Sy) and the box (Bx,By). Record the minimum cost known for reaching each position and do a BFS using a priority queue to find the shortest path to a position where the box reaches the target cell. this is the code generated...
Input format

The first line consists of two integers r and c (both ≤ 20), representing the number of rows and columns of the maze, respectively

Following this are r lines each containing c characters. Each character describes one cell of the maze. A cell full of rock is indicated by a '#' and an empty cell is represented by a '.'. Your starting position is symbolized by 'S', the starting position of the box by 'B' and the target cell by 'T'.

Output format

If it is impossible to bring the box to the target cell, print -1.

Otherwise, output two integers P and W on a single line, where P is the number of pushes and W is the number of walks in an optimal solution.

```
     HERE IS THE CODE.... my problem is  when input is:
    7 11
    ###########
    #T##......#
    #.#.#..####
    #....B....#
    #.######..#
    #.....S...#
    ###########
     output appears as -1. whereas it should hav been 6 22
```

please tell me what is the error in the code..

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <queue>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    const int MAX = 20 + 5; 
    char map[MAX][MAX]; 
    int visPerson[MAX][MAX];
    int visBox[MAX][MAX]; 
    int R, C;
    int dir[4][2] = {{0,1}, {0,-1}, {1,0}, {-1,0}};
    char pushes[4] = {'E', 'W', 'S', 'N'}; 
    char walks[4] = {'e', 'w', 's', 'n'}; 
    string path; 
    struct NODE 
    {
     int br, bc; 
     int pr, pc; 
     string ans; 
    };
    int InMap(int r, int c) 
    {
     return (r >= 1 && r <= R && c >= 1 && c <= C);
    }
    int Bfs2(int sr, int sc, int er, int ec, int br, int bc, string &ans)
    {
     queue<NODE> q; 
     NODE node, tmpNode; 
     node.pr = sr; node.pc = sc; node.ans = "";
     q.push(node);
     visPerson[br][bc] = 1; 
     while (!q.empty()) 
     {
     node = q.front();
     q.pop();
     if (node.pr==er && node.pc==ec) { ans = node.ans; return 1; }
     if (visPerson[node.pr][node.pc]) continue;
     visPerson[node.pr][node.pc] = 1;
     for (int i=0; i<4; i++) 
     {
     int nr = node.pr + dir[i][0]; int nc = node.pc + dir[i][1];
     if (InMap(nr, nc) && !visPerson[nr][nc] && map[nr][nc] !='#')
     {
     tmpNode.pr = nr; tmpNode.pc = nc; tmpNode.ans = node.ans+ walks[i];
     q.push(tmpNode);
     }
     }
     }
     return 0;
    }
    int Bfs1(int sr, int sc, int br, int bc) 
    {
     queue<NODE> q; 
     NODE node, tmpNode; 
     node.pr = sr; node.pc = sc; node.br = br; node.bc = bc; node.ans ="";
     q.push(node);
     while (!q.empty()) 
     {
     node = q.front();
     q.pop();
     if (visBox[node.br][node.bc]) continue;
     visBox[node.br][node.bc] = 1;
     if (map[node.br][node.bc] == 'T') 
     {
     path = node.ans; return 1;
     }
     for (int i=0; i<4; i++) 
     {
     int nextr = node.br + dir[i][0];
     int nextc = node.bc + dir[i][1];
     int backR = node.br - dir[i][0];
     int backC = node.bc - dir[i][1];
     string ans = ""; 
     if (InMap(backR, backC) && InMap(nextr, nextc) && map[nextr][nextc] != '#'&& map[backR][backC] != '#' && !visBox[nextr][nextc])
     {
     if (Bfs2(node.pr, node.pc, backR, backC, node.br, node.bc, ans))
     {
     tmpNode.pr = node.br; tmpNode.pc = node.bc;
     tmpNode.br = nextr; tmpNode.bc = nextc;
     tmpNode.ans = node.ans + ans + pushes[i];
    q.push(tmpNode);
     }
     }
     }
     }
     return 0;
    }
    int main()
    {  int push=0,walk=0,len;
      string str;
        int i=1;
        int r=0;
     int sr, sc; 
     int br, bc; 
     int cases = 1; 
     cin>>R>>C;
     for (int r=1; r<=R; r++) 
     {
     for (int c=1; c<=C; c++)
     {
     cin >> map[r][c];
     if (map[r][c] == 'S'){ sr = r; sc = c; } 
     else if (map[r][c] == 'B') { br = r; bc = c; } 
     }
     }
     path = ""; 
     r= Bfs1(sr, sc, br, bc);
     if (r)
     {
        str=path;
        len= str.size();
        int a1= count(str.begin(),str.end(),'s');
        int a2= count(str.begin(),str.end(),'w');
        int a3= count(str.begin(),str.end(),'e');
        int a4= count(str.begin(),str.end(),'n');

        cout<< len - (a1+a2+a3+a4) << " " <<(a1+a2+a3+a4) << "\n";
     }
     else
     cout<< "-1"<<"\n";
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are there any inputs w/ a solution which this *does* work on?

Comment: yes.. @ScottHunter it works on this one                                                               INPUT :8 4
 ....
.##.
.#..
.#..
.#.B
.##S
....
###T                                                                                                   output is : 3  16